# Finding a user with highest post created in last 24 hours, laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to find the user with the highest post created in the last 24 hours in laravel?
sorted by the number of posts in descending order.

Comment: highest post is interger or string?

Comment: Highest post? What exactly do you mean by highest? Points? Comments? etc

Comment: Number of posts created by the user

Comment: Ah! Is Post a model in you application?

Comment: Yes! Model User has many Post.
The Tricky part is i want to rank the user by the number of posts created in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Check my answer below and tell me if that works or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you are asking for the users with the highest number of posts created in the last 24 hrs.

To accomplish this, do the following:

```php
$users = User::withCount(['posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('created_at', '>=', carbon()->now()->subDay());
        }])->orderBy('posts_count', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

As the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) states, you can add constraints to the queries.

> ### Counting Related Models
>
> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the
>   `withCount` method, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on
>   your resulting models. For example:
>
> ```php
> $posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();
>
> foreach ($posts as $post) {
>     echo $post->comments_count;
> }
> ```
>
> You may add the "counts" for multiple relations as well as add
>   constraints to the queries:
>
> ```php
> $posts = Post::withCount(['votes', 'comments' => function ($query) {
>     $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
> }])->get();
>
> echo $posts[0]->votes_count;
> echo $posts[0]->comments_count;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In regular SQL syntax you'd need something like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), user_id
FROM posts
WHERE created_at = today
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

It gets all the posts, groups them by `user_id`, sorts them with the highest `user_id` count up top and gets the first record.

I am by no means an expert on SQL, let alone the query builder in Laravel, so someone else would probably be better at writing that.

I know that you can get the posts that were created today by using Carbon, like so:
`Post::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->get();`

---

EDIT: This might work for you:

```
$last24h = Carbon::now()->subDay();

DB::table('posts')
  ->select(array(DB::raw('COUNT(id)', 'user_id')))
  ->where('created_at', '>=', $last24h)
  ->groupBy('user_id')
  ->orderBy('COUNT(id)', 'DESC')
  ->limit(1)
  ->get();
```

Be sure to include `use Carbon\Carbon` to be able to use Carbon.

This should give you both the amount of posts and the corresponding user id.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

get user id:

```
 $minusday = Carbon::now()->subDay();
 $user_id = DB::table('posts')
            ->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(id) as total'))
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $minusday)
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderBy('total','desc')
            ->limit(1)
            ->get();
```